# Printing Government paper form from website

Tags: html, css, printing

We have to recreate a Government form from our website. The form is full of vertical and horizontal lines and different width and height cells. Some cells contain pre-printed text and have two or three lines of data.

We have created the Web page to capture and validate the dynamic data and now need a method of rendering the form (A4) to the printer. The client does not want a classic PDF print preview so our normal reporting tool will not work. Can anyone guide me on how to create a print output using css, html with vertical and horizontal lines and positioned data.

Comment: This is not a jobs board. You write code, we (maybe) try to help fix it.

Comment: Which is to say, if you give us some code, tell us what isn't working, tell us what you tried, we'll try to help

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I affended this board, I was actually trying to get some guidance from the experts

Our current code is below.  We use Jaspersoft Ireports to design the form layout and the PHPJasperXML library to render a PDF and write a copy on the server.
I have to rewrite this using CSS & HTML and render in an Iframe with an immediate (kiosk) print. I'm just looking for the right approach before I go down the wrong route.

```
include "config.php";
$version="0.9d";$pgport=5432;
$pchartfolder="./class/pchart2";
$ecsd_id = $_REQUEST['ecsd_id'];
include_once('class/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
include_once("class/PHPJasperXML.inc.php");
ob_clean();
$PHPJasperXML = new PHPJasperXML();
//$PHPJasperXML->debugsql=true;
$PHPJasperXML->arrayParameter=array('ecsd_id'=>$ecsd_id);
$PHPJasperXML->load_xml_file("ecsd_pdp.jrxml");
//$PHPJasperXML->transferDBtoArray($server,$user,$pass,$db);
$PHPJasperXML->transferDBtoArray($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
//$PHPJasperXML->load_xml_file("ecsd_pdp_copy.jrxml");
$PHPJasperXML->outpage("I");
$PHPJasperXML->outpage("F", "ecsd_prints/" . $ecsd_id . ".pdf");
//page output method I:standard output  F =save as filename and submit and parameter as destinate file name D:Download file
```